# Properly type function object argument TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function somewhere in the code`setTouched({ ...touched, [name]: true });`  which accepts an object. The name property is dynamic, it can be 'email', 'password' or whatever. 'touched' object can empty.
This is my interface:

```
interface IInputFieldProps {
    setTouched: () => void;
}
```

Currently it is just a function that returns nothing.
I tried `setTouched: ({[key: string]: boolean}) => void`. Looks like it doesn't work.
How can I properly type object as a function argument using TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

`({[key: string]: boolean})` does not contain types but rather an invalid destructuring. Types must go on the right side of the colon:

```
interface IInputFieldProps {
    setTouched: (data: {[key: string]: boolean}) => void;
}
```